# What is the meaning of the "Do not turn off" label on the switch in Jimmy's office?

Tags: plot-explanation, analysis, better-call-saul

In [S2E1 "Switch"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_(Better_Call_Saul)) Jimmy moves into a new office and his attention is brought to a sign "Do not turn off" taped over a switch on the wall. He looks at it and decides to flip it anyways. What is the meaning of that?

Comment: @Paulie_D. This question is obviously intended for those who have seen the show. Nothing happens when he flips the switch. But there was some time spent to show this to the viewers and I was wondering what was the purpose of that.

Comment: The purpose is probably that he couldn't resist doing what the sign told him not to.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It wasn't shown what (if anything) the switch controls in the office building. I think the symbolism of the switch is more important to the story. The sign on the switch says that it must always stay on. It's even taped over the switch, so it's impossible to flip the switch without noticing the sign.

[image: Switch - Better Call Saul]

But Jimmy can't resist. He doesn't play by other people's rules, so he removes the sign and flips the switch to see what will happen. This gives you a sense of Jimmy's state of mind as he starts this new chapter (the job at his new law firm) and provides an interesting contrast to his reaction to another sign in the episode.

Remember that the black & white flashforward scene at the beginning of the episode has Jimmy/Saul/Gene trap himself in a trash room. When the door latches behind him, he sits and waits for a janitor to come and let him out, instead of just opening the door because a sign tells him that an alarm will sound and the police will be dispatched. He doesn't want that to happen, so he obeys the sign. This tells you that Jimmy has gone through a transformation. *Better Call Saul* is the story of how he becomes Saul Goodman, the character in *Breaking Bad*. The events of *Breaking Bad* transform him again, into Gene, a manager of a Cinnabon in Omaha who plays by the rules, even though he doesn't like it.

Comment: I agree with the message, but you also have to remember that Jimmy's an outlaw in the flashback, so avoiding police interaction is in his best interest as well.